# Convert bitwise int values into a Day of month mask

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, common-table-expression

I apologize if I seem unknowledgable. I have only been writing T-SQL for about 3 years now and most is self-taught. At my work we store Day of month values in bitmasks.  eg. 1xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx converts to 1, and 12345678910111213141516171819202122232425262728293031 converts to 2147483647.  What I want/need to do is convert the int value into a varchar(64) containing numbers and 'x' characters.  I have the following code from another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127116/sql-server-convert-integer-to-binary-string) on here that kind of does something similar with some tweaking, but it provides the data backwards (right to left [as it should for binary] instead of left to right).

```
    declare @i int /* input */
    set @i = 42

    declare @result varchar(32) /* SQL Server int is 32 bits wide */
    set @result = ''
    while 1 = 1 begin
     select @result = convert(char(1), @i % 2) + @result,
           @i = convert(int, @i / 2)
     if @i = 0 break
    end

    select Replace(@result,'0','X')
```

It also does not provide all of the characters.  All 31 characters must be backfilled.

I have also played with [Rob Farley's Simple Recursive CTE](http://msmvps.com/blogs/robfarley/archive/2006/10/20/Simple-recursive-CTE.aspx) for this.

Comment: "12345678910111213141516171819202122232425262728293031 converts to 2147483647" - How? Surely a bitmask would only be ones and zeros?

Comment: @Phil the 53 character string `12345678910111213141516171819202122232425262728293031` has all 31 days of the month concatenated. `1111111111111111111111111111111` in binary = `2147483647` in decimal.

Comment: Oh, I see. It wasn't immediately obvious!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a numbers table to split the `@i` into bits, then concatenate the bits into a `varchar(32)` value:

```
DECLARE @i int = 42;

WITH bits AS (
  SELECT
    number,
    B = CASE @i & POWER(2, number - 1) WHEN 0 THEN 'x' ELSE '1' END
  FROM master..spt_values
  WHERE type = 'P'
    AND number BETWEEN 1 AND 31
)
SELECT CAST((
  SELECT '' + B
  FROM bits
  ORDER BY number
  FOR XML PATH ('')
) AS varchar(32))
```

Result:

```
--------------------------------
x1x1x1xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

This solution uses a system table called [`master..spt_values`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4273723/what-is-the-purpose-of-system-table-table-master-spt-values-and-what-are-the-me) as a numbers table, but it's never a bad idea to [generate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10819/sql-auxiliary-table-of-numbers) and use your own instead.

Comment: Thanks! I apologize, I just saw this... I was not alerted to it being answered!  I will try this at the first possible opportunity.