# Convert returned char from substring to binary

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, binary, binary-search

I have written the following query:

```
substring(SELECT DB_NAME()), 1, 1)
```

I wish to convert the char which this query returns in to a binary string like "11001101".

What is the correct way to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could use ASCII() to convert the character to a decimal integer and then use the script given on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127116/sql-server-convert-integer-to-binary-string) answer to convert that to a "binary" string

You will possibly end up with something like this:

`DECLARE @i INT = ASCII(SUBSTRING((DB_NAME()),1,1))
SELECT
    CASE WHEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), @i &   128 ) > 0 THEN '1' ELSE '0'   END +
    CASE WHEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), @i &    64 ) > 0 THEN '1' ELSE '0'   END +
    CASE WHEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), @i &    32 ) > 0 THEN '1' ELSE '0'   END +
    CASE WHEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), @i &    16 ) > 0 THEN '1' ELSE '0'   END +
    CASE WHEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), @i &     8 ) > 0 THEN '1' ELSE '0'   END +
    CASE WHEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), @i &     4 ) > 0 THEN '1' ELSE '0'   END +
    CASE WHEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), @i &     2 ) > 0 THEN '1' ELSE '0'   END +
    CASE WHEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), @i &     1 ) > 0 THEN '1' ELSE '0'   END`